# How to export the same function but with different parameters by export

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I need to export the same pre-defined function, but with different parameters by export.

What I'm trying to achieve:

```
module.exports = {
    adminSaysHello: sayText("Hello", "admin"),
    adminSaysText: sayText(text, "admin"),
    sayText: sayText
}

function sayText(text, author){
    console.log(`${author} said: ${text}`);
}

module.adminSaysHello();
module.adminSaysText("Good Bye");
module.sayText("Hello, my name is Foo", "Foo");
```

When executing above script I get the following error:

```
    adminSaysText: sayText(text, "admin"),
                           ^

ReferenceError: text is not defined
```

How to do this export correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to create additional functions which then call the original function with specific parameters. That will look something like this:

```
module.exports = {
    adminSaysHello: () => sayText('Hello', 'admin'),
    adminSaysText: (text) => sayText(text, 'admin'),
    sayText: sayText
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should make use of closure functionality in JavaScript to make it work. Try this

```js
module.exports = {
    adminSaysHello: sayText("Hello", "admin"),
    adminSaysText: sayText(text, "admin"),
    sayText: sayText
}

function sayText(text, author){

  return function(){
    console.log(`${author} said: ${text}`);
  }
}

module.adminSaysHello();
module.adminSaysText("Good Bye");
module.sayText("Hello, my name is Foo", "Foo");
```